# Rep total fluctuates briefly for 12 hours then returns to normal

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Sorry for the horrible title, I'm not sure how better to phrase it.

2 days ago I had 1740 points, then 2 hours later my total had moved up to 1840 points, and I noticed I had 10 upvotes on 10 different questions. A little strange but excellent I thought and carried about my business. I checked again a day later and the 10 upvotes had disappeared and my total had gone back to 1740.

What gives? is this just some weird bug or reconciliation error?

Comment: You've got a lot more votes like that.  There might be another big rep drop in the future when user accounts get merged.  Best to flag a moderator and get it taken care of now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like the 10 upvotes were all from the same user and thus the [vote fraud detection script](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) (which runs periodically) cancelled them out.

Comment: Ah-ha, thanks for this, everyday is a school day!